# How to Detect Collision when a gameobject collide with a lineRender?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to draw some lines by dragging the mouse. I did that using this script .

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private LineRenderer line;
    private bool isMousePressed;
    private List<Vector3> pointsList;
    private Vector3 mousePos;

    // Structure for line points
    struct myLine
    {
        public Vector3 StartPoint;
        public Vector3 EndPoint;
    };
    //  ----------------------------------- 
    void Awake()
    {
        // Create line renderer component and set its property
        line = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.material =  new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Additive"));
        line.SetVertexCount(0);
        line.SetWidth(0.1f,0.1f);
        line.SetColors(Color.green, Color.green);
        line.useWorldSpace = true;  
        isMousePressed = false;
        pointsList = new List<Vector3>();
//      renderer.material.SetTextureOffset(
    }
    //  ----------------------------------- 
    void Update () 
    {
        // If mouse button down, remove old line and set its color to green
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = true;
            line.SetVertexCount(0);
            //pointsList.RemoveRange(0,pointsList.Count);
            line.SetColors(Color.green, Color.green);
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = false;
        }
        // Drawing line when mouse is moving(presses)
        if(isMousePressed)
        {
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            mousePos.z=0;
            if (!pointsList.Contains (mousePos)) 
            {
                pointsList.Add (mousePos);
                line.SetVertexCount (pointsList.Count);
                line.SetPosition (pointsList.Count - 1, (Vector3)pointsList [pointsList.Count - 1]);
                if(isLineCollide())
                {
                    isMousePressed = false;
                    line.SetColors(Color.red, Color.red);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //  ----------------------------------- 
    //  Following method checks is currentLine(line drawn by last two points) collided with line 
    //  ----------------------------------- 
    private bool isLineCollide()
    {
            //  if (gameObject.tag == "default") {

                        if (pointsList.Count < 2)
                                return false;
                        int TotalLines = pointsList.Count - 1;
                        myLine[] lines = new myLine[TotalLines];
                        if (TotalLines > 1) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < TotalLines; i++) {
                                        lines [i].StartPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [i];
                                        lines [i].EndPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [i + 1];
                                }
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < TotalLines - 1; i++) {
                                myLine currentLine;
                                currentLine.StartPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [pointsList.Count - 2];
                                currentLine.EndPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [pointsList.Count - 1];
                                if (isLinesIntersect (lines [i], currentLine))
                                        return true;
                        }
            //  }
        return false;
    }

    //  ----------------------------------- 
    //  Following method checks whether given two points are same or not
    //  ----------------------------------- 
    private bool checkPoints (Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB)
    {
        return (pointA.x == pointB.x && pointA.y == pointB.y);
    }
    //  ----------------------------------- 
    //  Following method checks whether given two line intersect or not
    //  ----------------------------------- 
    private bool isLinesIntersect (myLine L1, myLine L2)
    {
        if (checkPoints (L1.StartPoint, L2.StartPoint) ||
            checkPoints (L1.StartPoint, L2.EndPoint) ||
            checkPoints (L1.EndPoint, L2.StartPoint) ||
            checkPoints (L1.EndPoint, L2.EndPoint))
            return false;

        return((Mathf.Max (L1.StartPoint.x, L1.EndPoint.x) >= Mathf.Min (L2.StartPoint.x, L2.EndPoint.x)) &&
               (Mathf.Max (L2.StartPoint.x, L2.EndPoint.x) >= Mathf.Min (L1.StartPoint.x, L1.EndPoint.x)) &&
               (Mathf.Max (L1.StartPoint.y, L1.EndPoint.y) >= Mathf.Min (L2.StartPoint.y, L2.EndPoint.y)) &&
               (Mathf.Max (L2.StartPoint.y, L2.EndPoint.y) >= Mathf.Min (L1.StartPoint.y, L1.EndPoint.y)) 
               );
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FTu0.png)
Now How to print something when my line collide with some gameobjects in the scene???
It means that when the line collide with my gameobject i want to say go to another scene.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Raycast from LastPosition to CurrentPosition in Update method.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html
Example:
http://xenforo.unity3d.com/threads/general-purpose-method-for-better-collision-solving.64781/

Comment: Instead of just providing url, you should also provide code samples. Sometimes, the url may no longer be valid and that would make this answer to be useless.

Comment: My line doesn't have any collider with script i did something to detect collision when lines collide to each other.But, the line does not collide with other game objects it just collide with it self like the photo i have upload it.

Comment: @NewHacker The raycast is meant to hit the collider on any objects, not the other lines. This won't interfere with your current line intersection tests.

Comment: Ok Tnx a lot I will do it :)